# É possível rodar um executável do Windows armazenado na memória?

Tags: c#, windows, memória, assembly, runtime

Eu tenho um executável que **não é um assembly do .NET Framework** armazenado num `byte[]`, e pretendo executar ele sem criar um arquivo dedicado a ele por questões de segurança.

O motivo de não querer criar um arquivo temporário, armazenar os bytes e então executar é porque o Executável contém informações sensíveis, além de estar encriptado, e pode ser facilmente burlado e acessado pelo usuário ao abrir o arquivo criado.

Então, já tentei usar esse método:

```
byte[] assemblyFiles = Decrypt(assemblyBytes);
Assembly executeable = Assembly.Load(assemblyFiles); 
executeable.GetEntryPoint().Invoke();
```

Porém, na hora de usar o `Assembly.Load()` ele dá erro e diz que o executável não é válido para .Net Framework.

Eu precisava fazer isso em C#, de preferência dentro do próprio aplicativo, sem precisar de um arquivo dedicado a esta operação.

Eu já tentei usar [essa classe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3553875/load-an-exe-file-and-run-it-from-memory) de outra resposta no StackOverflow inglês, mas não entendi como usar o argumento `hostProcess`. Portanto, não tive sucesso.

Comment: Até é possível, mas isto não dá segurança alguma. Se tem informações sensíveis e nada que faça dará segurança. E não pode usar a infraestrutura do .NET para carregar nele algo que não foi feito para ele. O caminho seria o da pergunta do SOen.

Comment: Alguma dica de como implementar isso? Eu tentei injetando no próprio executável com `Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location` porém o que eu consegui foi travar o sistema com mais de 500 processos do mesmo assembly.